# Dynamic link button not firing in update panel

Tags: asp.net

I'm dynamically adding a link button in the footer of a grid view.  The grid view is wrapped in an update panel.  I can get an async post back (I can tell by seeing an update progress flash), but I can't get the debug point in my click function to fire.

```
Private Sub gvParts_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvParts.RowDataBound
 ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        If _showPrice Then

            Dim clearbutton As New LinkButton
            clearbutton.ID = "btnClearCart"
            clearbutton.Text = "Remove All"

            ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(clearbutton)
            e.Row.Cells(7).Controls.Add(clearbutton)

            AddHandler clearbutton.Command, AddressOf clearButton_click

        End If
    End If

Private Sub clearButton_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ClearCart()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<dl>




Private Sub gvParts_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvParts.RowDataBound
     ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
            If _showPrice Then

                Dim clearbutton As New LinkButton
                clearbutton.ID = "btnClearCart"
                clearbutton.Text = "Remove All"

                ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(clearbutton)
                e.Row.Cells(7).Controls.Add(clearbutton)

                AddHandler clearbutton.Command, AddressOf clearButton_click

    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(clearbutton)

            End If
        End If
```

**Sorry,It's my mistake I have posted wrong code.Place the above code on `OnRowCreated` event of gridview**

try this

```
  Private Sub gvParts_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvParts.RowDataBound
     ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
            If _showPrice Then

                Dim clearbutton As New LinkButton
                clearbutton.ID = "btnClearCart"
                clearbutton.Text = "Remove All"

                ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(clearbutton)
                e.Row.Cells(7).Controls.Add(clearbutton)

                AddHandler clearbutton.Command, AddressOf clearButton_click

    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(clearbutton)

            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The controls have to be added to your Controls collection prior to the page_load event.  The default databinding (which fires the OnRowCreated, OnRowDataBound events) happens during the OnLoad event.  Try moving your databinding code to the Page_Init function.  Depending on what your databinding code looks like, this might mean you will have to implement the databinding "manually"  (ie.  Set the datasource and call .DataBind() in code)